# Flutter/Dart LDAP Login system

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, authentication, ldap

I have already created a **Flutter** app with a complete Sign up - Login system using **Firebase** and now it is needed to be re-imagined with **LDAP** authentication.

I have already established a connection to the company server using [dartdap](https://pub.dev/packages/dartdap) and the [example](https://pub.dev/packages/dartdap/example) they posted. Or at least I think I did, because the log doesn't print '********* Exception'.

So now I only need a way to send my credentials to the server and await confirmation? I am kinda lost. With Firebase I used:

```
onTap: () {
  AuthController.instance.login(
      _emailController.text.trim(), _passwordController.text.trim());
},
```

What would be the equivalent of the above? And also, am I missing something?

Comment: I don't think SAML is supported in flutter yet https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/discussions/7626

Comment: @AlexanderN. So wait, what does [dartdap](https://pub.dev/packages/dartdap) do then? What do I do now?

Comment: Sorry, I was attempting to indicate that I don't believe flutter+firebase support SAML. I'm not 100% sure though